# Weird fragment shader behaviour upon two conditions

Tags: opengl-es, shader, fragment-shader

I'm developing an Android app that uses OpenGL-ES, and recently I've ran into a very bizarre issue when coding in the fragment shader. I have my textures, and I'm trying to draw a pixel grid in them with the following code:

```c
#type fragment
#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D uTexture;

in vec4 fColor;
in vec2 fTexCoordinate;

out vec4 color;

void main() {
    if (fColor.xyzw == vec4(0, 0, 0, 0)) {
        float x = fTexCoordinate.x;
        float y = fTexCoordinate.y;
        float targetX = round(x * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
        float targetY = round(y * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
        bool paintVertical = abs(x - targetX + 0.0001) < 0.0001;
        bool paintHorizontal = abs(y - targetY + 0.0001) < 0.0001;
        if (paintHorizontal) {
            color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            return;
        }
        color = texture(uTexture, fTexCoordinate);
    } else {
        color = fColor;
    }
}
```

When I run the program with this shader, the horizontal lines are perfectly drawn (they seem unaligned due to the distance):
[image: Red lines generated by the shader.]

Now, if I replace `if (paintHorizontal)` with `if (paintVertical)`, I also get a correct result:

[image: Vertical lines.]

But if I simply do both at the same time, with `if (paintHorizontal || paintVertical)`, I get this weird result:

[image: Unaligned lines.]

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly a precision issue, try `precision highp float;`.

Comment: That was it, thank you! Still wonder why it didn't happen with a single bool though, but oh well...

Comment: `mediump` is just a hint - the compiler probably used an fp32 in the original shader because it was mostly scalar code and wasn't worth vectoring, but bothered to use a vec2 fp16 in the second case which had more vectorization opportunity.